# Reduce List<T> using BiFunction<T, T, Mono<T>>

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have `List<T>`, I need to reduce it using `BiFunction<R, T, Mono<R>>` aggregator.

So I need to chain those monos (`Mono<R>`)
How this can be done using project reactor?

UPDATE: 
For example, I have a list with item1, item2 etc...
I have a function `Mono<R> reduce(T item, R acc)`

I need something like this: `reduce(item1, startAcc).flatMap(acc -> reduce(item2, acc)).flatMap(acc -> reduce(item3, acc))` etc.

I can implement this using recursion, but I get StackOverflowError if the list is long enough

Comment: Can you share input and the desired output, so that I can then suggest the code.

Comment: @VikramRawat I have List<T>,

Comment: @VikramRawat I have `List<T>`, also I have a function `Mono<R> reduce(T item, R acc)`

I need to get Mono<R>

so, basically, it's something like this:
`reduce(item1, startAcc).flatMap(acc -> reduce(item2, acc)).flatMap(acc -> reduce(item3, acc))....`

Comment: I can implement this using recursion, but StackOverflowError is thrown when it's a long list

Comment: This is a known bug - https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1441

Answer (score -1):

You should simply use the **reduce method available on Flux**. Sample code below:

```
public void reduceTest() {

    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    Flux<Integer> numberFlux = Flux.fromIterable(numbers);

    Double initial = 2.5;
    BiFunction<Double, Integer, Double> multiply = (doubleNumber, numberInt) -> doubleNumber * numberInt;

    Mono<Double> floatResult = numberFlux.reduce(initial, multiply);        
    floatResult.subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

Please refer the Java Docs at https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need this for `BiFunction<R, T, Mono<R>>`
Your variant has BiFunction<R, T, R>

Comment: But after the first reduce, you again do a flatMap so essentially you are always using the value of the Mono for the next reduce method. So, why not do all the reduction and finally have a Mono?

Comment: I don't get what you are suggesting.
I can think of this:

`  
        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().collect(toList());
        Flux<Integer> numberFlux = Flux.fromIterable(numbers);

        BiFunction<Mono<Double>, Integer, Mono<Double>> multiply = (doubleNumber, numberInt) -> doubleNumber.flatMap(acc -> Mono.just(acc * numberInt));

        Mono<Double> floatResult = numberFlux.reduce(Mono.just(2.5), multiply).flatMap(mono -> mono);
        floatResult.subscribe(System.out::println);
`

But, if you specify 10000 as an upper value, you get StackOverflow